# Rails saving many to many only saves one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship in my models:

```
class ClientProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_folders
  has_many :folders, through: :client_folders

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :folders
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :client_folders
  has_many :client_profiles, through: :client_folders
end

class ClientFolder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_profile
  belongs_to :folder
end
```

I have the relationships built up in controller:

```
@client_profile = ClientProfile.new
2.times do |i|
  @folder = Folder.new(folder_name: "folder #{i}")
  @client_profile.folders << @folder
end
```

I have the following fields_for associations created in view:

```
<%= form_for @client_profile do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :folders do |folder_builder| %>
      <%= folder_builder.text_field :some_column %>
      ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And the create action:

```
  def create
    @client_profile = ClientProfile.new client_profile_params
    if @client_profile.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

When I save the association, it does create the client_profile as well as the two folders, and the join model ClientFolder is correctly created twice. However in both ClientFolders created, it only has the folder_id filled in. The client_profile_id is left null.

One solution I tried is adding the following to client_profile to ensure it saves the join model relation correctly:

```
  def folders_attributes=(params)
    if params["0"][:id].nil?
      params.values.each do |v|
        f = Folder.new v
        self.folders << f
      end
    end
  end
```

But this raises the following exception when saving:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for #<ClientFolder:0x007fd364743d78>:
  activemodel (4.1.5) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:208:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:349:in `save_collection_association'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:186:in `block in add_autosave_association_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:157:in `instance_eval'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:157:in `block in define_non_cyclic_method'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:306:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:482:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:103:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:268:in `block in save'
```

Someone else recommended to add the join model association:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_folders
```

But it doesn't make sense to do that, since I am not using client_folders at all in the form.  When I use fields_for :folders in form, it should be intelligent enough to save the join model properly in create.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please put also your ````create```` action from controller?

Comment: @Esse I added it but it is not much. It just calls save.

Comment: I don't really know answer - but from my experience using ````accepts_nested_attributes_for```` usually yields terrible developer experience ;) One suggestion i may take is replacing ````@folder = Folder.new(folder_name: "folder #{i}")
  @client_profile.folders << @folder```` with ````@folder = @client_profile.folders.new(folder_name: "folder #{i}")````. However I would **strongly** consider changing it into form objects - you can find railscast here http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects
(trust me, it's a lot better way)

Comment: @Esse Any idea where that NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for is coming from?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm avoiding accepts_nested_attributes_for whenever possible.

I think it may be problem with this method "folders_attributes=(params)" being called by ````self.folders << f```` - which saves association. Maybe add something like: ````super unless params.values```` (but this seems like terrible hack)

Comment: @Esse if I do not add "folders_attributes=(params), then when it saves join model, it leaves the client_profile_id column null. That's why I added "folders_attributes=(params) in the first place, to try to force the saving of the association properly.

Comment: @Esse I figured out the problem. I defined the join model twice in the model, one as a has_many and the other as a has_one. That is what was causing the problem. Once I removed that, I didn't even need the folder_attributes=(params) anymore, it just saved everything automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem.

I had defined the relation twice in the model:

```
  has_many :client_folders
  has_one  :client_folders, :class_name => 'ClientFolder', :foreign_key => :folder_id
```

When I removed that has_one, everything worked accordingly.